# Problema con peticion de Axios en producción

Tags: vue.js, sailsjs, axios

Estoy realizando la siguiente petición con Axios y Vue.js

```
saveImage:()=>{
        var formData = new FormData();

        formData.append('image', app.course.image);
        formData.append('course_id', app.course.id);


        axios.post('/api/v1/course/uploadimage', formData, {
            headers: {
                'mimeType':'multipart/form-data',
                'contentType': false,
            }
        }).then(function (response) {

        }).catch(function (error) {

        });
    },
```

funciona cómo debería en entorno local, pero al desplegarlo en un droplet de digital ocean, en el controlador solo recibe la imagen (app.course.image), pero course_id (app.course.id) llega como indefinido. ¿Cómo puedo resolverlo?

Comment: Porque usas una funcion flecha? tuve el mismo problema muchas veces con ese tipo de funciones en VUE.. es que no se llevan bien, en realidad VUE de alguna forma no logra que las propiedades sean reactivas de esa forma. Lo probaste como una funcion normal?

Comment: eso no solo es un tema de sintaxis? nunca me ha dado problemas usarlo con VueJs. De todos modos lo cambíe para probar y me sucede lo mismo, en local funciona, pero ya en producción no.

Comment: ok. no tenes ningun error en la consola?

Comment: y de donde salen app.course en los dos casos?

Comment: son parte de data de la instancia de vue:
data: {
       course:{},
       lessons:[],
       message:''
    }

Comment: entiendo que ande local.. pero no hay ningun error de consola? si lo pones local pero en modo produccion, pasa lo mismo?

Comment: en un method previo, cargo course.image con el archivo de la imagen redimencionado (esto funciona bien ya que la imagen si llega al controlador y se guarda con normalidad, perro el valor de course_id es el que llega como indefinido por loq ue no puedo relacionar la ruta de la imagen con el 'course' que corresponde en la base de datos)

Comment: y se cargan desde el mismo lugar? no puede haber un problema de cors?

Comment: no entiendo muy bien a qué te refieres, pero al analizar data de vue, course tiene sus atributos y entre ellos id.

Comment: y podes mandar por consola el formdata, a ver si esta completo y el problema esta en otro lado?

Comment: espera.. como analizas el data de vue en produccion???

Comment: vue no está en producción, por lo que tengo entendido para que esté en producción tengo que agregar el js mimificado nada más, pero ahora estoy agregando el js normal, por lo que con un complement de firefox puedo ver el data de vue.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82669/discussion-between-gbianchi-and-kevin-puscan-ortiz).